# How do I get Drupal Contact module to send email (on a shared server)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, contacts

I'm not having much luck with this one. On my site I've set the email address in Site Configuration>Site information and i've allowed permissions for the contact module. Indeed, when the user enters their details and presses the submit (send e-mail button) the message flashes up "Email has been sent". But nothing happens. I've had a word with my hosting provider but he says "you just need to use authentication with a valid email address and password hosted on the server. You should be using the pear smtp method." Do I have to write some php using the pear smtp method? I thought Drupal would already do this?

Comment: Did you set your recipient(s) at /admin/build/contact/list ?

Comment: Yes - one of the first things I did. The form wouldn't work otherwise?

Comment: The one thing I can manage is getting the contact mail to go to the authorised email account for that domain. Fine for me, but not brilliant for people I set up on Drupal, unless I can set up some auto-rules for forwarding on email? Or adjust their email client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your logs and make sure it's being sent to the right destination, or see if there are some details about any errors there.

If you do need to setup SMTP auth, it looks like there are a few options for that (see http://drupal.org/project/smtp) for example.

Comment: I've looked into the smtp module, but it needs phpmailer setting up, and the host provider maintains it's not necessary..

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  If your provider is requiring you to use SMTP auth, how do they expect you to do that? Two questions - 1, Is there anything helpful in your logs? 2, if you don't mind letting us know who your provider is, it might be possible to figure out something with that info.

Comment: Well my provider is a small outfit here in the UK, so you probably won't know their set-up. I've managed fairly easily to get the contact module to send to the webmail enabled for the domain, so it's not a programming issue, something I have to sort with the host provider